# Calculate a short vertical distance traveled by iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, cocoa-touch, core-motion

Currently I'm working on an app which needs to detect if the iPhone starts and stops moving vertically. I need to be able to detect a pretty short (50-100 cm) vertical distance traveled, i.e. if a person performs a squat.

Is there a way to calculate that the [Core Motion framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion)?

```
let motion = CMMotionManager()

if motion.isDeviceMotionAvailable {
    self.motion.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 1.0 / 60.0
    self.motion.showsDeviceMovementDisplay = true

    self.motion.startDeviceMotionUpdates(using: .xMagneticNorthZVertical, to: .main, withHandler: { (data, error) in
        if let validData = data {
            // Just a random minimum acceleration threshold                    
            if validData.userAcceleration.y > 3 {
               print(validData.userAcceleration.y)
            }
         }
     })
}
```

Comment: Core Location's `CLLocationManager` has an altitude property that is returned as part of the `CLLocation` object. But having just noticed you wrote `cm` and not `m` I guess that wouldn't be accurate enough :)

Comment: Does this help? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremotion/cmaltitudedata

Comment: You could use math to convert the acceleration into speed, and then into position change. If you've ever taken a calculus course, you'll know that there'll be some pesky constants in the way, so you may need to have a "calibration" step, where you'll ask the user to stay still and then measure static acceleration (aka gravity), or alternatively you could use the camera to get this extra data. If it's just for squats, then you could probably make it work with just math though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to calculate vertical distance traveled with the Core Motion framework?

Core Motion can detect attitude (how the phone is oriented) and acceleration (how the phone starts or stops moving, speeds up or slows down). A smooth vertical movement would not register at all. You might know that the movement started and ended, but not how far apart those events occurred. You might guess something about that based on the initial acceleration (which could let you calculate how fast we got going) and the time before deceleration. But it wouldn’t be very much more than a guess.

Comment: So you're saying it's not technically possible to detect if a person makes a full squat?

Comment: There is no “squat” in your question. I say nothing about that. I'm saying what I’m saying. There is nothing inherent in the phone sensors that tells you the phone is now located 2 feet closer to the ground. If the squat is fast and sudden enough you can sense the start and stop as jerks and guess that it is a squat. You could certainly _count_ those gestures. But you cannot be certain it’s a squat or know exactly how deep it is.

Comment: Your edit doesn't change anything about my answer. You ask what the CoreMotion framework is capable of detecting and I've answered. You will need to collect the data into a buffer and analyze it for acceleration and deceleration and use the amounts and the intervening time to guess that this is a squat and what the distance travelled over that time might be, as I said in my answer. If I were you I would start by doing some squats yourself, collecting the data, so that you can see what the data looks like.

Answer (score 1):

Well had to do a bit of similar work for one of the apps I worked on earlier. So the key is to use all the sensors you can access. Accelerometer, gyroscope, GPS, and magnetometer (Probably not the GPS and compass in your case). Then the next step is to perform a few full squats(Hopefully Your office is ok with this :-) as you expect your user to while getting a baseline on the data. Then you can build up a model on this.

Well if you want to be really cheeky, You can do what we did, we sent these sensor data to a ML API/Model. Over time it became really accurate. Now we are more than 90% accurate. However, this might be overkill in your case.